# How to prevent words from breaking in textview when using wrap_content?

Tags: android, textview, android-wrap-content

I am in the process of trying to convert a desktop app to Android - and am struggling with some very basic stuff.

When I specify a layout including a textview that holds a sizable amount of text `wrap_content` seems to arbitrarily break in the middle of a word and I can not find any documentation indicating this can be controlled.

Comment: Are you seeing this exhibited on an actual device as well as the emulator in addition to the graphical representation of the xml view?

Answer (score 0):

Try useing [Ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) property of TextView.

"If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle"

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this since none of the other solutions worked for me.

I had copied and pasted some text from online and I didn't realize it had weird spacing characters in that caused the text to wrap mid-word rather than at whitespace.

Here is the nasty character `" "` that looks like a space but isn't actually a space. I did a find and replace for this character and that solved my problem.